# Change div background color if checkbox inside is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, checked

I'm looking for a way to change the div background color which is the parent of a checkbox. However I only want it to change background color when the attribute 'checked' is inside the tag.

**HTML**

```
<div class="company">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Selected[]" class="checkboxC" value="8" checked>
             Company 8
</div>
<div class="company">
        <input type="checkbox" name="Selected[]" class="checkboxC" value="9">
             Company 9
</div>
```

So in the example above, I'd only want the div with checkbox 8 to change background color. 9 Stays the default color. I also can't do anything with the name attribute because that's taken by PHP. Any help on how I can fix this using Javascript/jQuery?

Comment: did you at least read my answer?

Comment: Yes I did. But your code only works when you click it, right? Not when it's already checked in html. Thanks for the help anyway :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to update the parent background color of all those checked inputs once the document is ready:

```
$(function () {
    $('input:checked').parent().css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

See a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pgo7kd5g/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works. I changed it a bit so it checks all checkboxes. Here's the code for anyone interested:

   $('.checkboxC').each(function(i, obj){
    
    $('input:checked').parent().css('background-color', 'red');    
    if($(obj).is(':checked'))
    {
        $(obj).is(':checked').parent().css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});